# No Suitable method found to override error for a method with generic type as parameter

Tags: c#

I'm getting the - No Suitable method found to override error for a method with generic type as parameter. Please help

```
public abstract class DocumentController<T> : Controller where T : class
{

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual Response Update([FromBody]T entity)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class DocumentDetailsController : DocumentController<Details>
{

    [HttpPost]
    public override Response Update([FromBody]T entity)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I note that you should have gotten *two* errors: that no method is found that can be overridden, and that `T` is not defined. It's the second error message that you should have read and understood, since it is identifying the problem: there's nothing named `T` in your class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the parameter type in the `Update` method:

```
public override Response Update([FromBody]Details entity)
```

The generic argument `T` is declared in the parent type. You specify `T` as `Details` here:

```
DocumentDetailsController : DocumentController <Details>
```